# Disable a button without using setEnabled property

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button where the selector is like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_circle_selected"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_circle_disabled" />
</selector>
```

So when I click the button, the background will show a red colored circle.
I need to disable this button based on condition, so the highlight should not be shown.

If I so it as setEnabled false it will work
But there is one more case where the disabled button should give auditory feedback.

So when I give setEnabled as false the other requirements will not work because touch is disabled.

Is there any method to disable the button other than setEnabled ()?

Comment: Have u tried `yourButton.setClickable(false);`

Comment: yes..Still it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the above by custom selector where the button appears to be disabled but the fact it is still enabled and trigger click actions.
you can use

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_circle_disabled />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_circle_disabled"/>
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_circle_disabled" />
```

also don't forget to keep track to the button status (enable/disabled)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider setting the attributes of the button programmatically from the java file, not XML.
Give the button an id from your XML layout file, then reference it from the java file. In that way, you will have more control over how it behaves.

For example, `android:id="@+id/my_button"` in the XML. 
Then `Button button = findViewById(R.id.my_button);` in the `onCreate` method.

Afterward, give it whatever attributes you want.